# С помощью mysql phpmyadmin заменить или удалить некоторые теги

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

На сайте есть такие теги:

```
<td data-label="Текстовый123">3281.501</td>
```

Написал такую команду:

```
UPDATE px_post SET post = REPLACE( post, '<td data-label="[а-яА-Яa-zА-Z]">[1-9]</td>', '' );
```

Но здесь что-то не то. Как делать так, чтобы убрать или заменить этот тег из сайта с помощью phpmyadmin?

Comment: В базе хранится сам тег? Возможно, что при генерации страницы из базы берутся нужные данные и потом на их основе создаётся тег? А вообще двойные кавычки значимей одинарных. У вас в запросе внутри одинарных двойные стоят

Comment: @Pashok, да, в базе хранится сам тег. Простые теги как "<br>" и т.п. удалось удалить, хотелось бы и эти теги вместе с содержимым удалить, они не нужны для моих статей.

Comment: какой результат ожидаете от этого запроса? какие условия для обновления/замены?

Comment: @Novitskiy Denis, Удалить или заменить то, что указал. Например было так: `Текст 1 <td data-label="Текстовый123">3281.501</td> Текст 2` после замены чтобы стало так: `Текст 1 Текст 2` Статей более 5000, эти теги везде

Comment: что общего у этих тегов? какая-то часть повторяется? есть похожие теги, которые нужно оставить? или все удалить?

Comment: @Novitskiy Denis, Например, в этом теге: `<td data-label="Текстовый123">3281.501</td>` Они все отличаются значением `data-label` и содержимым (в данном случае `3281.501`, везде они разные). Их хочу удалить полностью, хочу только оставить текст который до них и после них

Comment: просто заменить через replace не получится (ему нужно точное вхождение). из решений - только разбить строку на части и затем снова склеить. это единственные теги в строке? или в ней присутствуют и другие?

Comment: @Novitskiy Denis, Понятно. Да, это единственные что нужно заменить

Comment: @Ilnyr если это единственные теги в строке, то проблем вообще не должно быть - отрезаете текст по <td> и </td> и соединяете